# Exponential map in Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to show

$$\exp(tX)\exp(tY) = \exp(t(X + Y) + t^2/2[X,Y] + o(t^3))$$

In a normal neighbourhood I can write

$$\exp(tX)\exp(tY) = \exp(Z(t))$$

so if I do the Taylor expansion of $Z(t)$ we have the next expression

$$Z(t) = Z(0)+ Z'(0)t + Z''(0)t^2/2 + o(t^3)$$

Is easy to see that $Z(0) = e$ and $Z'(0) \equiv X + Y$. So... I dont know how to proceed

Comment: It's classical : see Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula